# Jquery Connected Lists - Updated Serialized list value in input fields

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

Guyz, I am trying to solve a problem.

I have two lists that are sortable with connectWith in jQuery. I am trying to make a process that updates every time an item is moved from one list to another that updates two hidden input fields with the serialized list of id's from each list.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"

    }).disableSelection();
});
```

I would like to do this:

```
    var list = '';
    $('#sortable1 *').each(function() {
        list += $(this).attr('id') + ',';
    });
    alert('list = ' + list);
```

but on every change it would update two input fields instead of doing an alert with the list.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```
$(function() {
    var lists = $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        update: function() {
            var list = [];
            lists.each(function(){
                $.merge( list, $(this).sortable("toArray"));
            });
            $("#out").text( list.join( "," ) );
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/eTwzF/